# Can global adversaries 'de-anonymize' any TOR user in a day?

Tags: deanonymization

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/tor-traffic-correlation-attacks-by-global-adversaries

I know what traffic correlation attack is but I find it hard to understand this article or how it got to its conclusions about 'de-anonymize' 'typical web user' who use TOR within a day just with the ability to monitor enough web traffic. I also don't get how dark markets and child porn still exists on onion sites if all it takes is a little bit of cooperation to de-anonymize everyone?, The article is from 2013 so the governments had a long time to do it.

At the end all what the 'global adversaries' can see is traffic volume and timing(that is affected by some timing noise) right? so if you are just a typical web user who just connected few times(lets say 5 times) to an average website/webpage with an average size of 700kb who said that you are one of the few TOR users who visited a website/webpage in this size 5 times around the time you did it?. 
I am missing something here?.

Answer (score 0):

> Can global adversaries 'de-anonymize' any TOR user in a day?

No they can't.

From all of the information that has been leaked, even powerful governments have a hard time de-anonymizing Tor users. See Snowden's book and others' for more information on that. If you want to discuss traffic correlation and other attacks, then that is best for the [Tor mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-talk) with the people who know best.